# war file in client-side deployment

Tags: java, war

How to set a password in war file ??? Can i set the IP address,mac address in war file then before the deployment this war check the IP address ,mac address?If those address correct then war file deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do IP address check,mac address check etc inside war so even if war is deplyod it will not work if ip or mac address is incorrect. ie....Change the code in war like that

A sample java program to get IP address and MAC address is given below

```
 import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.NetworkInterface;
    import java.net.SocketException;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    public class MACandIP{

       public static void main(String[] args){

        InetAddress ipAddress;
            byte[] macAddress;
        try {

            ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("IP address =" + ipAddress.getHostAddress());
            NetworkInterface networkInt = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ipAddress);
            macAddress = networkInt.getHardwareAddress();
            StringBuilder strBld = new StringBuilder();
                    System.out.print("MAC address = ");
            for (int i = 0; i < macAddress.length; i++) {
                strBld.append(String.format("%02X%s", macAddress[i], (i < macAddress.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
            }
            System.out.println(strBld.toString());

 //in above code assume you got MAC address as  81-7B-39-C5-A6-D4 

                if(strBld.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("81-7B-39-C5-A6-D4")){
                    // mac is correct 
                }

        } catch (UnknownHostException excep) {

            excep.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SocketException exce){
            exce.printStackTrace();
        }

       }

    }
```

Comment: how to set client mac address in war file.Then war file deploy only that mac address.Give me code?

Comment: if you change code inside war then everyone can deploy war but only those users with correct IP(or MAC) can use it

Comment: I know this one.But my question is how to set mac adddress (checking process) in war file?

Comment: In this code mac address can't check define client mac address?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14115/discussion-between-fathah-rehman-p-and-shubhanshu)

Comment: thanxs for your advice ....your code will run.thanxs again.but if mac address is not matched loop is not print the catch exception...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not doing all this validation inside the war file, after all this is just a file and if someone want to replace it he can just replace the file no matter what validation and checking you did in the war.

What you need to do is to write a deployment script that you give it the new war to deploy and then the script do all your validations and replace the war file.

Comment: question is how to secure war file deployment .If that client sends this war file another place the war file doesn't work?any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The WAR format and servlet API does not support any form of protection before deployment.  Additionally any software-only scheme can be cracked.

A combination of a valid license key which you check for and a "code is unsupported without a valid license" is most likely the best you can expect.